# How to make a Nucleo-H743ZI2 as EtherCAT master?

Tags: keil, stm32cubeide, ethercat, stm32h7

I have a NUCLEO-H743ZI2 board and also a LS L7NH Servo Driver which supports EtherCAT for communication. I want to send my commands to the driver via NUCLEO board so I want to make it an EtherCAT master. Is that possible and how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are open source EtherCAT Masters available here:

https://etherlab.org

https://openethercatsociety.github.io/

Acontis Technologies also offers a paid commercial solution: https://www.acontis.com/en/ethercat-master.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. But how can I implement it with open source EC masters? Actually I'm very new in Ethercat.